# Angular4 mat-form-field textArea can not enable horizontal resize

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, textarea

I am trying to use `mat-form-field` component with a `textarea` , I would like to be able to resize on x and y. 
But adding `resize: both;` did not make it work, what is the solution for that?

Code:

```
<mat-form-field style="resize: both;">
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying it to the `textarea` will allow you to resize on x and y within the `mat-form-field`...

```
<textarea style="resize:both" matInput placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
```

This unfortunately only allows the textarea to resize within the `form-field`

- With all of the nested div elements that make up the `mat-form-field`
  wrapper, attempting to apply this to all of them will likely end up with nested drag corners and not one seamless resize-able element.

[image]